# How to record sound coming through left and right channels in a 3.5mm cable in a laptop(Windows)

Tags: virtualization, windows-11, audio-recording, headphone-jack, 3.5mm

I want to record sound which is coming from another PC though output(3.5mm jack). I don't want to externally join left or right channels to the microphone slot in the 3.5 mm cable. In the receiver computer(connected through 3.5mm male-male connector) I want to record from the headphone output line(here it is input). Which method I need to use, I tried VB-Audio virtual cable, but it does not work with external sound coming through the headphone outputs(only works with sound generated in the same computer itself)

Answer (score 1):

You'd need an external USB sound card capable to taking a stereo/dual mono line in. A headphone jack is no use to you; a) it's mono & b) it's mic level, line levels would completely overpower it.

Cheaper alternative would be to just record the other machine internally & pass the resulting file over.

Comment: Lets say I cannot install anything in the other machine, can't plug any usb device there. Is there any way to receive audio from the audio jack from this device(using a custom driver or anything)? From the other device the sound must come from 3.5 mm audio jack, I don't care about sound amplitude(I can use amplifier in between that is not my question).

Comment: It's not getting audio out, that's the easy bit. Headphone level is not far from line level by the time you've added a bit of impedance. It's getting it into the second computer. You can't get stereo into a headphone jack & the other machine's headphone out would be massively too loud for the mic input… hence the USB sound device. They used to put stereo line in on computers… one of the things it's cheaper to just leave out. Every so often someone wants to do it… & discovers they can't.